# Terminator is not working!

Tags: debian, terminal, gnome-terminator

**Terminator** is my choice of terminal in **debian**. I seem to have broken it while playing with its profile preferences.

I can't open it normally as other applications. However **after becoming root** I can access it through **gnome-terminal**. When it opens, the following warning pops up:

`An error occurred while loading or saving configuration information for terminator. Some of your configuration settings may not work properly.`

Details :

`No D-BUS daemon running`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried purging the package and then reinstalling it?

```
apt-get purge terminator
```

Then delete configuration files located in your home directory

```
rm -rfvI /home/your_user_name/.config/terminator
```

This should remove all the config files. Now reinstall.

```
apt-get install terminator
```

Comment: Yes I did. But the problem prevails!!

Comment: Do you have the `~/.config/terminator/config` file? If so you might have to manually delete it.

Comment: Yes did it, but still not working.

Comment: Ok so just to make sure, you purged the package with `apt-get purge terminator` then deleted all config files from your user's directory (not root's home directory by accident). I suggest specifying your user's home directory rather than using `~` like `rm -rfvI /home/your_user_name/.config/terminator`. Then reinstall terminator. If this does not do the trick then I'm stumped.

Comment: I had deleted the config files from the root directory. Sorry, my bad!! Problem solved :D thanks to you :)

Comment: Glad to help, i will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing entire Terminator, just purge its configuration file and restart.
This hack work for me

```
sudo rm ~/.config/terminator/* -rfv
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't face this issue in ubuntu normal flavor, but with ubuntu-gnome, I had to install python-psutil to run it.

`sudo apt-get install python-psutil`

and then try opening terminator

Answer (score 0):

Instead of purging entire Terminator, just purge its configuration file and restart. It will work for sure.

```
sudo rm ~/.config/terminator/config
```